# Maximum contiguous subsequence -- dynamic programming or greedy algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an array `vector<int> arr` with positive and negative entries, the maximum contiguous subsequence problem requires to find a (contiguous) segment of the array `arr` with maximum sum. Sum of empty segment is zero. The C++ code of the algorithm I'm using is as follows:

```
  int MaxContSum(const vector<int>& arr){
    int i,sum=0,max=0;
    for(i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
      if(arr[i]>=0) {if(sum<0) sum=0;}
      else {if(sum>max) max=sum;}
      sum+=arr[i];
    }
    if(sum>max) max=sum; return max;
  }
```

Is this algorithm a greedy algorithm or dynamic programming? It looks like it's just scanning the entries one by one and applying different strategies based on whether `arr[i]` is potive or negative, a locally checkable condition. Why does this problem appear in the dynamic programming chapter, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Kadane's algorithm for the maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm). It scans through the sequence and keeps track of the maximum subarray sum found up to this iteration in general, and the maximum subarray sum ending exactly at this point. How does it know the starting position of the subarray leading to the best sum up to exactly this point? Whenever 1) the previous sum is negative, and 2) a positive element is encountered, it pays to start at the positive element and continue from there. The proof that it works is by simple induction.

This algorithm is not greedy, but it can be viewed as dynamic programming.

A greedy algorithm makes a locally-optimum guess, and sticks with it (just continuing it further and further). Here, conversely, the algorithm can guess to check a subsequence starting at some point (where the sum ending at a positive element is negative), and later discard it and try a subsequence starting at some other point (again, because the sum becomes negative and the element is positive).

Conversely, it can be viewed as a dynamic programming problem. As the Wikipedia entry puts it:

> Because of the way this algorithm uses optimal substructures (the maximum subarray ending at each position is calculated in a simple way from a related but smaller and overlapping subproblem: the maximum subarray ending at the previous position) this algorithm can be viewed as a simple example of dynamic programming.

Comment: I see. The condition `sum<0` is not locally checkable, because the variable `sum` carries information from the past to the current state. This problem shows the advantage of studying history -- to change a greedy decision-making strategy into dynamic programming. Our previous people have done a "subproblem" for us. We can choose whether we want to inherit or discard the legacy based on information that was not available to them.

Comment: `max` records the result of terminating the segment, and `sum` records the result of not terminating the segment. Both possiblities are played out, and the decision is made when both payoffs are clearly seen in the `if(sum<0) sum=0;` step. A greedy algorithm would make an early decision and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Two main properties that problem should have in order to be eligible for solving with DP are:

- [Overlapping subproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems)
- [Optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure)

From what you presented, first property is definitely missing and therefore I wouldn't classify this algorithm as DP. On the other hand, you use the result of the calculation for the smaller problem to get a final result - so we have Optimal substructure and that is probably the reason why you found this algorithm in the dynamic programming chapter, even though it should not belong there.